# Where are GUI handles managed?

Tags: winapi, handle, user32

As I understand from windows internals, handles of executive objects are not managed by the same entity as handles you get from functions like `CreateWindow()` or `LoadCursor()` and such.

What dll/sys is responsible for these ones returned by functions from `user32.dll`? Is there some program like WinObj for this kind of handles?

I would be happy even for some keywords to google, havent had any luck on keywords tagged on this question.

Comment: The `TEB` contains some of that information for usermode: http://undocumented.ntinternals.net/UserMode/Undocumented%20Functions/NT%20Objects/Thread/TEB.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**win32k.sys** is responsible for handling USER and GDI requests.

> The win32k driver is a critical component in the graphics stack
>   exporting more than 600 functions. It extends the *System Service
>   Descriptor Table (SSDT)* with another table called
>   _W32pServiceTable. This driver is not as big as the main kernel module (ntoskrnl.exe) but its interaction with the user-mode is just
>   as important. The service table for win32k contains less than 300
>   functions depending on the version of Windows. The win32k driver
>   commonly transfers control to user-mode with a user-mode callback
>   system. The interface between user-mode modules and kernel-mode
>   drivers has been built in order to facilitate window creation and
>   management.

Detailed information: http://mista.nu/research/mandt-win32k-paper.pdf

Comment: Since NT4, it should be added. Before that MS had experimented having this in usermode ;) +1

Comment: Yes, in NT4.0 0 a large part of USER components was moved from CSRSS (user-mode) to win32k.sys (kernel-mode)

Comment: I have this quote in my documents, bud I add another source with similar answer. :)

Comment: Wow, honestly I haven't really expected to be so lucky to get the full answer :) thanks a lot.